# Spring REST API Controller is redirecting to home when authenticated with token

Tags: java, spring, rest, redirect, token

I have an API REST Controller on my Spring 4 application that returns JSON values but somehow, **looking at the logs**, the dispatcher redirect the request to '/'.

```
2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:221 - Written [{"type":"groupmatch"}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@4617ede3]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:115 - Chain processed normally
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/'; against '/'
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:180 - / has an empty filter list
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:319 - Looking up handler method for path /
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:326 - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.thebetcafe.controllers.HomeController.home(org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1241 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'static/home.html'; URL [static/home.html]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG JstlView:166 - Forwarding to resource [static/home.html] in InternalResourceView 'static/home.html'
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/static/home.html]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:319 - Looking up handler method for path /static/home.html
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:329 - Did not find handler method for [/static/home.html]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:191 - Matching patterns for request [/static/home.html] are [/static/**]
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:220 - URI Template variables for request [/static/home.html] are {}
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:141 - Mapping [/static/home.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/static/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@6a23a6d6]]] and 1 interceptor
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/static/home.html] is: -1
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
    2016-04-01 11:30:35 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
```

I have a specific filtering to authenticate the user via a token in the header but I am not sure how it can be generated by that. Here is the code:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class APIController {
    ...
        @RequestMapping(value="/groups",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            public @ResponseBody String getAllGroups(){
                List<CompetitionGroup> groups = groupService.findAllGroups();
                return groupListToJSONObject(groups);
            }
    ...
    }
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- SCANNING THE COMPONENT -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:property-placeholder/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
```

pom.xml

```
<!-- Jackson (JSON) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you please mention the URL, you are hitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a specific filter for JWT token authentication below:

```
public class JWTTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JWTTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);

    public JWTTokenAuthenticationFilter(){
        this("/api/");
    }

    public JWTTokenAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JWTSuccessAuthenticationHandler());
    }

    public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "Authorization";

    @Override
    protected boolean requiresAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another method to authenticate request headers
     */
    @Override public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new JwtTokenMissingException("No JWT token found in request headers");
        }

        /* Try to parse the token */
        AppUser userDetails = jwtUtil.parseToken(header.substring(7));
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> auth = new ArrayList<>();
        auth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userDetails.getRole().name()));

        JWTAuthenticationToken token = new JWTAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getEmail(), userDetails, auth);
        token.setAuthenticated(true);

        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

        // As this authentication is in HTTP header, after success we need to continue the request normally
        // and return the response as if the resource was not secured at all
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

The trick is that the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` was redirecting the request to '/' when authenticating.

So I created a new `JWTSuccessAuthenticationHandler` who does nothing after the authentication.

```
public class JWTSuccessAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        // We do not need to do anything extra on REST authentication success, because there is no page to redirect to
    }

}
```

Hope that helps someone :)